# Cloudflare caching deployment process?

Tags: docker, caching, server-side-rendering, cloudflare

We have website behind cloudflare and when we do deployments (docker or pm2), cloudflare caches broken instance or not finished instance for some reason, causing website to be broken and needing purge of cache manually.

What are the best practices that would prevent or utilizing caching better?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, Cloudflare is not as intelligent as a human, it's a bot, isn't it?

You may consider adding `page rules` to 'teach' Cloudflare doesn't cache the pages.

Comment: Right, it is bot, do we know how often it makes request to server to cache? I guess I could add some workaround into swarm script. Did consider removing caching altogether, not best option though

Comment: One word to say, randomly. It will randomly cache your content anypart, at anywhere in the global, at anytime a person visiting your website.